# **Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound** error on Neo4J

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I have installed Neo4J 4.1.0 on Windows 10. When I run the following command I get the error.

CALL algo.list()

**ERROR**

**Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound**

There is no procedure with the name `algo.list` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j 4.x does not support the [Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/) library.

Instead, you should be using the new [Graph Data Science](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/) library. In that library, the equivalent query would be `gds.list()`, as in:

```
CALL gds.list
```

Comment: Thank you very much cybersam. That worked. So I assume everything that was algo before is now gds?